# How to check if user has blank content inside tag when sending message [vue]

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

I'm wanting to show an alert to warn the user when the wrong tags are entered:

Ex:

> `<b></>` => false 
>  `<b>hello</>` => true 
> `<a >link</>` => false 
>  `<a https://www.google.com></>` => false
>
>  `<a https://www.google.com>link</>` => true

These are my rules:

```
  const rules = [
    [/<right>([^<]*)(<\/>)?/g],
    [/<center>([^<]*)(<\/>)?/g],
    [/<left>([^<]*)(<\/>)?/g],
    [/<a ([^>]*)>([^<]*)<\/>?/g],
    [/<([^>]*)>([^<]*)<\/>/g],
  ];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong tags"?

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions can simply understand that I enter any 1 tag but do not enter the content inside the closing tag ex: `<b></>` => false, sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like (considering `string` is your text):

True:

```
!!string.match(/<[^>]*>.+<[^>]*>/)
```

False:

```
!!string.match(/<[^>]*><[^>]*>/)
```

This would work for your cases but if it's something more complicated you would need to use recursive patterns (which afaik are not available in JS) - if you want to use strictly regular expressions.

For the exact use cases - something like this should work:

```
  const rules = [
    [/<right>.+(?<!>)<[^>]*>/g],
    [/<center>.+(?<!>)<[^>]*>/g],
    [/<left>.+(?<!>)<[^>]*>/g],
    [/<a\s+[^>]*>.+(?<!>)<[^>]*>/g],
    [/<[^>]*>.+(?<!>)<[^>]*>/g],
  ];
```

Comment: there is no way to iterate through an array of rules, like a function that can be reused in many places.

Comment: @hoangnv I don't understand - it's a single regex that works for all the above cases.

Comment: like in the example above `<a ></>` if I haven't unlinked it will show the message `you haven't entered a link` or if you haven't entered a display name it will `you haven't entered a display name`, so i want to check exactly the above cases

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/BXwucX/1 if you enter 2 nested closing tags like this, it must display as `b, u cannot be empty`, Sorry for my unclear description

Comment: @hoangnv I tried my best - check my updated answer and let me know if something else pop up.